# MVC: Edit Resource file for Globalization after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have multi language in my system using resource file. My current resource file setting is as below:

> Build Action: Embedded Resource
>
> Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy
>
> Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
>
> Custom Tool Names:

In my view, this is how I set my value from resource file:

```
@Project1.App_Global.Resource-en.Title
```

This work perfectly fine in my local and after deploying the application.

But right now I need to allow user to edit the resources file for all languages without the need of recompiling and deployment, so I need the resources file to be generated as an external file instead of compiling as a DLL in the bin folder.

I'm following some idea to allow the resource file to be generated as an external file by changing each resource file to following setting:

> Build Action: Content
>
> Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy
>
> Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
>
> Custom Tool Names:

But after the changes above, my application is throwing error at the part where I call `@Project1.App_Global.Resource-en.XXXX`. The exception is as below:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Project1.App_Global.Resource-en.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Project1" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

I tried deploying my application, I can see the resource files inside App_Global folder, but couldn't test because of the error.

Any advice on what am I missing? What is the correct way to retrieve the resource value in View?